# создание групповой хранимой функции mysql

Tags: mysql, функции

Вечер добрый. 
Родился у меня такой вопрос:

"как создать в mysql хранимую функцию, которая могла бы принимать в качестве аргумента набор данных?"

хотелось бы сделать функцию, которая, например, искала бы мне медиану, или какой-то N-ый элемент в массиве:

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo(**arg_array** { RANGE? | TABLE? | ARRAY?? }) 
RETURNS INTEGER
BEGIN
  DECLARE val INTEGER;
  DECLARE sum INTEGER;
  DECLARE done INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

  DECLARE EVENTCURSOR CURSOR FOR SELECT val FROM **arg_array**;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET DONE = 1;

    OPEN EVENTCURSOR;
        WHILE DONE=0 DO
                FETCH EVENTCURSOR INTO val;
                SET sum = sum + val;
        END WHILE;
    CLOSE EVENTCURSOR;
  RETURN val;
END;
```

А использовал бы ее так:

```
SELECT uid, foo(value)
FROM user_values
GROUP BY uid
```

Есть подозрения, что такое невозможно. Пишу сюда, чтобы окончательно убедиться.

Answer (score 0):

Создание аггрегирующей функции в mysql возможно только в [UDF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-udf.html), т.е. на компилируемых языках `C` или `C++`

Поэтому фактически - возможно, но радости от этого мало.

Comment: благодарю за ответ